# How do I ffmpeg to iterate through 10,000+ datetime stamped files

Tags: datetime, ffmpeg, filenames, timelapse

I have a large number of jpgs captured from a cctv camera which I mistakenly used a dashed date time stamp in my curl command.  The file names are

```
 Underwater-Cam-2017-10-20_17-58-22.jpg
```

If I do a wildcard I get

```
bash: /Applications/ffmpeg: Argument list too long
```

I understand from other posts that I don't want avoid the pattern being  expanded using a glob, but I'm not sure how to iterate through these files with multiple sequential numbers. I tried this consecutive integer counting sequence which is in retrospect obviously not going to work, but I lack enough knowledge to resolve this through searching.

```
/Applications/ffmpeg -y -i '/path/to/src/2017-10-20/Underwater-Cam-2017-10-20_%02d-%02d-%02d.jpg' -r 24 -vf "scale=hd720" -metadata:s:v rotate=0 -vcodec libx265 -preset veryfast -crf 24 -an -movflags +faststart /path/to/dest/uwcam-2017-10-20.mp4
```

I'm doing this on a mac using bash 4.

Comment: You used the glob pattern? `ffmpeg -framerate 24 -pattern_type glob -i "Underwater*.jpg" -vf "scale=-2:720,format=yuv420p" -metadata:s:v rotate=0 -c:v libx265 -preset veryfast -crf 24 -movflags +faststart output.mp4`

Comment: @llogan In the end changing the glob pattern to exclude the full path but retain the wildcard worked.  Obviously I had to change the directory to do it, but it worked.  It makes me wonder what the character limit for globs are.

Answer (score 3):

What about outputting the list to a file (without any globbing) and using `ffmpeg`'s [concat demuxer](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate)?

Example:

```
$ ls
Underwater-Cam-2017-10-20_17-58-21.jpg  Underwater-Cam-2017-10-20_17-58-23.jpg
Underwater-Cam-2017-10-20_17-58-22.jpg

$ find -type f -name '*.jpg' -printf '%P\n' | xargs -I {} echo "file '{}'" > list

$ cat list
file 'Underwater-Cam-2017-10-20_17-58-21.jpg'
file 'Underwater-Cam-2017-10-20_17-58-22.jpg'
file 'Underwater-Cam-2017-10-20_17-58-23.jpg'
```

And then `ffmpeg -f concat -i list ... <output>`

Comment: Although I didn't use this solution, as I just needed to removed the full path to make this work, I'm going to keep this one in my back pocket for next time.  I'm curious if I can do it without xargs though as macos seems to have issues with it.